# mockito verify interactions with ArgumentCaptor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

To check the number of interactions with a mock where the parameter in the method call is of a certain type, one can do

```
mock.someMethod(new FirstClass());
mock.someMethod(new OtherClass());
verify(mock, times(1)).someMethod(isA(FirstClass.class));
```

This will pass thanks to the call to `isA` since `someMethod` was called twice but only once with argument FirstClass

However, this pattern seems to not be possible when using an ArgumentCaptor, even if the Captor was created for the particular argument `FirstClass`

this doesn't work

```
mock.someMethod(new FirstClass());
mock.someMethod(new OtherClass());
ArgumentCaptor<FirstClass> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(FirstClass.class);
verify(mock, times(1)).someMethod(captor.capture());
```

it says the mock was called more than once.

Is there any way to accomplish this verification while capturing the argument for further checking?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I recommend using Mockito's Hamcrest integration to write a good, clean matcher for it. That allows you to combine the verification with detailed checking of the passed argument:

```
import static org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest.argThat;

verify(mock, times(1)).someMethod(argThat(personNamed("Bob")));

Matcher<Person> personNamed(final String name) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<Person>() {
        public boolean matchesSafely(Person item) {
            return name.equals(item.getName());
        }
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("a Person named " + name);
        }
    };
}
```

Matchers generally lead to more readable tests and more useful test failure messages. They also tend to be very reusable, and you'll find yourself building up a library of them tailored for testing your project. Finally, you can also use them for normal test assertions using JUnit's `Assert.assertThat()`, so you get double use out of them.

Comment: That does not really answer the OP's question, does it?

Comment: @fge: Strictly speaking, no it doesn't, but if we only ever answered exactly the question that was asked, this would be a much more boring place, and people would learn a lot less. I think this is the right solution to the overall problem presented, even if the actual question, as phrased, wasn't asking for exactly this.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution and the one i actually used

Comment: thank you so much for putting this up.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I couldn't understand the ArgumentCapture examples.  This is perfect though.

Comment: I would strongly support @RyanStewart's assertion above. Sometimes you need to address what the OP *should* really be doing, rather than answering their immediate question

Comment: @RyanStewart `times(1)` is the default on verify :)

Comment: Nice answer. Helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Note that you'll get a compile-time error like `no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Matcher<...> conforms to ArgumentMatcher<T>` if you have `import static org.mockito.Mockito.argThat;` - you need `org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest.argThat` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Quoting the docs:

> Note that an `ArgumentCaptor`**don't do any type checks**, it is only
>   there to avoid casting in your code. This might however change (type
>   checks could be added) in a future major release.

I wouldn't use an `ArgumentCaptor` for this. This class captures (literally) everything, despite what class was provided as it's `.forClass` argument.

To achieve what you want I suggest intercept the argument using Mockito's `Answer` interface:

```
private FirstClass lastArgument;

@Test
public void captureFirstClass() throws Exception {
    doAnswer(captureLastArgument()).when(mock).someMethod(anInstanceOfFirstClass());
    mock.someMethod(new FirstClass());
    mock.someMethod(new OtherClass());

    verify(mock, times(1)).someMethod(anInstanceOfFirstClass());
    //write your desired matchers against lastArgument object
}

private Answer<FirstClass> captureLastArgument() {
    return new Answer<FirstClass>() {
        @Override
        public FirstClass answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            TestClass.this.lastArgument = (FirstClass) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            return null;
        }
    };
}

private static Object anInstanceOfFirstClass(){
    return Mockito.argThat(isA(FirstClass.class));
}
```

Comment: There are two ways this could be simplified.  Just use the Mockito `isA` matcher, rather than the Hamcrest one.  Then you don't need to call `argThat`, and you certainly shouldn't have an extra method just to do it.  Also, you never need to write `times(1)`.  One-time verification is Mockito's default - simply omit the second argument to `verify`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know mockito had it's own version of `isA` which could be used. But I still prefer to clearly state the number of expected method invocations using `times(1)` or `only()`, for better readability (IMO).

Comment: This is a bit more verbose so it reduces readability of the test but it accomplishes the goal of having a reference at the end to the parameter. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use the the captor for the sake of capturing, then verify the number of invocations with each argument type separately.

```
    // given
    ArgumentCaptor<AA> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(AA.class);
    CC cc = new CC();
    // when
    cut.someMethod(new AA());
    cut.someMethod(new BB());
    cut.someMethod(new BB());
    cut.someMethod(cc);
    // then
    Mockito.verify(collaborator, atLeastOnce()).someMethod(captor.capture());
    Mockito.verify(collaborator, times(1)).someMethod(isA(AA.class));
    Mockito.verify(collaborator, times(2)).someMethod(isA(BB.class));
    Mockito.verify(collaborator, times(1)).someMethod(isA(CC.class));
    assertEquals(cc, captor.getValue());
```

Apparently the generic type of the captor reference doesn't affect anything at runtime.

Comment: Just a reminder: `capture()` is capturing all arguments, and `captor.getValue()` returns the last one that was used, regardless the class passed as an argument to `ArgumentCaptor.forClass`

Comment: This is the simplest solution. It works fine **if** one keeps @MarlonBernardes comment in mind. +1

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem today. I thought I could simply do something like

```
verify(mock).someMethod(and(isA(FirstClass.class), captor.capture()));
```

but I couldn't get it to work. I ended up with this solution:

```
@Test
public void Test() throws Exception {
    final ArgumentCaptor<FirstClass> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(FirstClass.class);

    mock.someMethod(new FirstClass());
    mock.someMethod(new OtherClass());

    verify(eventBus, atLeastOnce()).post(captor.capture());
    final List<FirstClass> capturedValues = typeCheckedValues(captor.getAllValues(), FirstClass.class);
    assertThat(capturedValues.size(), is(1));
    final FirstClass capturedValue = capturedValues.get(0);
    // Do assertions on capturedValue
}

private static <T> List<T> typeCheckedValues(List<T> values, Class<T> clazz) {
    final List<T> typeCheckedValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final T value : values) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(value)) {
            typeCheckedValues.add(value);
        }
    }
    return typeCheckedValues;
}
```

Note: if only one class needs to be captured in this way `typeCheckedValues` can be simplified into:

```
private static List<FirstClass> typeCheckedValues(List<FirstClass> values) {
    final List<FirstClass> typeCheckedValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Object value : values) {
        if (value instanceof FirstClass) {
            typeCheckedValues.add((FirstClass) value);
        }
    }
    return typeCheckedValues;
}
```