# Why does Mockito ArgumentCaptor subvert generics

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito

Mockito ArgumentCaptor seems to subvert generics as demonstrated by the following pseudo code.

```
public Class SomeClass{
   public void someMethod(Object msg){
       // do whatever
   }
}
```

A unit test is executed into which a mock of SomeClass is passed.
The following method calls are made on the mock.

```
someClass.someMethod(instanceA)
someClass.someMethod(instanceB) // where A & B are different classes
```

The unit test then performs the following >

```
ArgumentCaptor<A> argumentCaptorA = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(A.class);
ArgumentCaptor<B> argumentCaptorB = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(B.class);

Mockito.verify(someClass, times(2)).someMethod(argumentCaptorA.capture());
Mockito.verify(someClass, times(2)).someMethod(argumentCaptorB.capture());
```

Here's the problem >

```
List<A> listA = argumentCaptorA.getAllValues(); 
List<B> listB = argumentCaptorB.getAllValues();
```

Both listA & listB are of size 2 containing both instanceA & instanceB.

Why is this? Is it because at runtime the instanceA and instanceB arguments become Object when passed to someClass and that Mockito does not properly type check Object against the types of the ArgumentCaptors?

I was anticipating that the generics would ensure that listA would contain instanceA and listB would contain instanceB.

Comment: Seems this question is covered in the body of this question > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204453/mockito-verify-interactions-with-argumentcaptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the javadoc what you expected is not supported but might change (2.21.0 version):

> Note that an ArgumentCaptor *don't do any type checks*, it is only
>   there to avoid casting in your code. This might however change (type
>   checks could be added) in a future major release.

If you want to implement some differentiation of arguments you could try taking advantage of the [Answer](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html)